# HTML5 attribute "required" inside UpdatePanel, not working (asp.net 4)

Tags: asp.net, html, updatepanel

In my .aspx file, I have an UpdatePanel with some textboxes and a button. If I add the "required" attribute to the textboxes, the postback stops working. I can see in Firebug that it's not posting at all. If I remove the "require" attribute, it's working as it should. Am I doing something wrong here, or is it a way to fix it?

The code for the UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%# GetComments (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")) %>
        <div class="contact_form">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h2>Skriv en kommentar til oss!</h2>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" placeholder="Ditt navn" required  />
                    <span class="form_hint">Ditt navn skal stå her</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox" required placeholder="Skriv resultatet av 10 pluss 6 her" />
                    <span class="form_hint">Du klarer vel å regne ut 10+6? :-)</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" required placeholder="Din kommentar"  />
                </li>                                                                        
                <li>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdSaveComment" CssClass="button" runat="server" CommandName="SaveComment" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>' Text="Puliser kommentar" />
                </li>                                                                        
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: If you've marked a field as required, and that field is empty, then postback *should* stop working.

Comment: I am filling the textboxes with text of course :) Thats why it's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't get error. So, **if [required](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-required.php) field specified, an input field must be filled out before submitting the form**.

try giving some value in the textboxes.

**EDIT**

Though, I should have mentioned my previous answer as a comment. However, this seems to be a bug mentioned [here](http://asphtml5.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20HTML5%20input%20controls%20in%20UpdatePanel).

Comment: Look at my comment in the question

Comment: @SveinErik: it seems bug. please try doing this workaround http://asphtml5.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20HTML5%20input%20controls%20in%20UpdatePanel